# What are the limitations of BluePrism? What are the scenarios in which it cannot automate?

Tags: blueprism, rpa, automationanywhere

I would like to know the limitations of `BluePrism (BP)` and `Automation Anywhere (AA)` and which types of applications it cannot automate. In addition, what are the differences between AA and BP w.r.t. functionality and limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially both AA and BP can automate anything inside the direct environment they are installed at. Both cannot automate anything within a virtual machine, e.g. Citrix. This can still be done via 'surface automation', which is a fancy word for finding a group of pixels within a screenshot of the view you want to automate. Both AA and BP have these capabilities, although neither generate robust results. In general you just want to avoid such situations.

From my experience AA has more of a developer feel to it. It provides less visual readability, but more control. It also brings more responsibilities as the logging needs to be done manually where BP does it automatically. BP's interface is a lot more visual which makes it easier to read and thus understand. BP's built-in queue is also nice as you won't have to setup a database. Finally BP has a way better debugging system than AA.

I could go on listing differences and cons and pros, but to answer your question more concretely: Both AA and BP can do the same things well and the same things badly, given you know what you're doing in either tools. There's also some RPA tools which allow you to have user interaction whilst running the bot, kind of like a virtual assistant.

In the end you want to identify the process and **then** decide which RPA tool fits best.

Answer (score -2):

I use BP and the problem with BP  is,it cannot read complex captcha values.

Comment: Captchas are meant to be difficult to read by software. You either target specific captcha or use captcha solving services like "death by captcha"